# PHP Getting server url parameters

Tags: php

I am using the  following function to get my server URL :

```
/* get url parameters */

    function url() {
        return sprintf(
                "%s://%s%s", isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        );
    }
```

The following is my url :

```
http://enunua.com/emarps/recover_password.php
```

From the  above url ,  I want only the  following parameters as part of my url :

```
http://enunua.com/emarps/
```

that is excluding recover_password.php 
but the  above function gives me the  whole url inclusive of recover_password.php, 
Please advise how can I be able to get only :  http://enunua.com/emarps/ ?

Comment: return sprintf(
                "%s://%s%s", isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
        );

Answer (score 0):

You are using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which contains the whole Request-URL so also the "recover_password.php". You can use sth. like "strrpos" to get the URL without the filename.

Try to use this:

```
function url() {
    return sprintf(
        "%s://%s%s",
        isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
        substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') + 1)
    );
}
```